# need help understanding JS code

Tags: javascript, closures

Hi I am new to javascript and I cannot understand the following code:

```
var createAdders = function () {

    var fns = [];

    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

        fns[i] = (function (n) {
            return i + n;
        });
    }
    return fns;
}
var adders = createAdders();
adders[1](7); //11 ??
adders[2](7); //11 ??
adders[3](7); //11 ??
```

From what I understand 7 is being passed as an argument but `createAdders()` doesn't assign 7 to any variable so does that mean 7 is being passed to the very next function within `createAdders()` i.e the anonymous function and assigned to the variable `n`.

**Is my logic correct?**

The code above does seem to work but for every call the result is 11.
I found this code in a very reliable blog as an example to a situation where closures would be useful.The above code is then altered in the following way to cite the advantages of closures.

```
var createAdders = function () {
    var fns = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            fns[i] = (function (n) {
                return i + n;
            });
        })(i)     //// why is (i) used here? what purpose does it serve??////
    }
    return fns;
}

var adders = createAdders();
adders[1](7); //8 
adders[2](7); //9 
adders[3](7); //10
```

**Is the same logic applied here as well?**

**I need to understand how n is being assigned the value 7**

**Why is (i) being used at the end of the function in the new code?**

Comment: I'm intermediate in JS, and I cannot understand what's the 'n' too =))

Comment: The `n` is the argument being passed when the function is called.

Comment: This was a nice read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript , inner function always have access to their outer function variable even after the outer function is finished executing. This behaviour is called Closure.

In first snippet, you're iterating over 3 times and pushing the function inside an array.When the loop is finished executing your variable i is set to 4. And function you pushed inside the array has access to this variable . So no matter at what index of array you execute the function you always get 11 ( 4 + 7).

In Second snippet , you are using an self executing anonymous function to hold the value of i . This anonymous function gets immediately executed with every interation . Because of closure function defined inside this anonymous function has a reference to new value of i every time.

So you have a three function inside the array each with seperate value of i (1,2,3)
Writing second snippet as follows makes it more clear

```
var createAdders = function(){
var fns = [ ];
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) { 
    (function(a) {
        fns[a] = (function(n) {
            return a+n;
        });
    })(i)    
}
return fns;}
```

In javascript you can have function as return value. 
and secondly arrays can store function inside themself.

What your doing in code is pushing a function inside array which accepts a single argument and later invoking it.

```
adders[1](7);
```

can be broken down as follow

```
var fn = adders[1];
fn(7); //thats how n is set to 7
```

Comment: Self Executing is not the same as Immediately Invoked. Self executing is associated with recursion, a function that calls itself as in `function foo() { foo(); }`, meanwhile an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is what it says, a function expression that is immediately invoked: `(function(i){})(i)` as well as `(function(i){}(i))`. It is a small misinformation, but as many people also have this mis-info of calling IIFEs as self-executing - which they are not, unless it calls itself as in `(function foo(i){ foo(i+1); }(i))` -, it's a thing worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks, I did thought they both mean the same thing

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, we don't have block scope, only function scope.

In the first example, the only `i` declared belongs to the `createAdders` scope, meaning all functions created in the `for` loop will seek up in the scope chain the same `i` and return the same value. Explained with code:

```
//   here's the only `i` declaration
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

    fns[i] = (function (n) {
        return i + n; //this line will retrieve the `i` variable declared above,
                      //that being always 4 after the loop ends
    });
}
```

In the second example, you're creating a new scope with an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) inside the loop - it creates a new execution context for each iteration.

A function created inside of the IIFE will access the IIFE's execution context's `i`. This `i` is unique for each iteration as you're passing the outer `i` to the IIFE, which becomes the IIFE's formal parameter `i`.

In short, each iteration creates a new execution context with its own `i` through an IIFE wrapper.

Read the comments in order:

```
//  1. Outer `i` declared here
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    (function (i) {// 3. Outer `i` becomes the formal parameter `i` of the IIFE, 
                   // it is a "different" `i` in a new execution context (scope)
        fns[i] = (function (n) {
            return i + n; // 4. seeks the `i` value of the IIFE
        });
    })(i) // 2. Outer `i` passed to IIFE
}
```

When you invoke the function(s) created inside of the IIFE, the scope chain will retrieve the "closest" `i` in the scope chain, that being the formal parameter `i` of the IIFE in which the function was created.

Comment: stop editing please. I am trying to read. :(

Comment: Was trying to make it easier to read. `:P`

Answer (score 1):

In the first block, the `createAdders()` return an array of functions, and every function (created in the inner `for` loop of the `createAdders()` function body) sums the parameter `n` (the 7 value) with the variable `i` created in the loop, wich, at the end of the loop, has the value of 4 (that explains the 11).

When you made the invocation `adders[1](7)` the function stored in the array `fns` at position 1 is returned, then you invoke the function with the parameter `n = 7`, then the function proceeds to sum this parameter with the `i` variable of the `createAdders` function (which value is `4` at the moment invoke `adders[1](7)`)