# Statically pass variable to function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For easier explanation, please see the corresponding [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zs9Z/2/)

This is the code I'm calling in a loop:

```
var eventNames = ["click", "dblclick", "contextmenu"];
for (var i = 0; i < eventNames.length; ++i) {
    var crtName = eventNames[i];
    $("#" + crtName).click(function () {
        alert("Event " + crtName);
    });
}
```

---

Sure, when the handler is called, `crtName` is always `"contextmenu"` because at this point, the `for`-loop has ended and `i` is always pointing to the highest possible value.

**Note:** In the current example, I'm using the `click` function from jQuery. In my real application, there's another framework being called to register an event handler. So this is just an example and it cannot be changed. Neither can I add parameters being passed to the handler when the event occurs. Therefore it's not a jQuery question.

As well, it's similar to the question "[need help understanding JS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458889/need-help-understanding-js-code)", except for the important fact that I'm not calling my event handler myself!

**Basically:** I would like the variable `crtName` to be populated when the handler is being *registered*, **not** when it's *called*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue:

> JavaScript's scopes are function-level, not block-level, and creating
>   a closure just means that the enclosing scope gets added to the
>   lexical environment of the enclosed function.
>
> After the loop terminates, the function-level variable `crtName` has the value
>   `contextmenu`, and that's what the inner function 'sees'.

So you can do,

```
var eventNames = ["click", "dblclick", "contextmenu"];

for (var i = 0; i < eventNames.length; ++i) {
    var crtName = eventNames[i];
    attach_event(crtName);
};

function attach_event(crtName) {
    $("#" + crtName).click(function () {
        alert("Event " + crtName);
    });
}
```

Read More about closures:

1. [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)
2. [Javascript closure insideloops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)
3. [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

### <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9zs9Z/3/)</kbd>

Comment: @djay please check updated ans with references given

Answer (score 0):

As Pilot said, you need to use a closure, like this:

```
(function (crtName) {
    $("#" + crtName).click(function () {
        alert("Event " + crtName);
    });
})(crtName);
```

This way, you pass `crtName` to a self invoking function that gets executed with the right event name for each member of the array

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using `crtName` to refer to the element's ID, just reference `this.id` inside the event handler

Comment: thanks for your message. As written in the example, the jQuery-way is only used to simplify the example code and to create a runnable jsFiddle. Therefore, this isn't a solution. =(

Comment: If you're using the variable to set the type of event, consider also using `evt.type` to get the event type.